# Do I place a comma when omitting "that," in this sentence?

Tags: commas

For some reason, I feel like this sentence doesn't look right without a comma when I omit "that"

**Original sentence:** He stopped so abruptly that red dust kicked up.

**To:** He stopped so abruptly red dust kicked up.

**Or?** He stopped so abruptly, red dust kicked up.

As far as I know, it should be written without the comma, but it's driving me crazy because I feel like it only reads correctly with the comma. Someone tell me I'm wrong here.

Comment: The one with the comma sounds like a list or a progression (he stopped so abruptly, then red dust kicked up) while the other one does not.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: I might be wrong, but that's just the way I see it personally

Comment: I suspect it's a matter of taste. The OED's examples (sense 25) have a comma, but the latest is 1859 (and not an exact match), so I don't think they can be relied upon for modern usage (they have from 1697 "He...treads so light, he scarcely prints the Plains", so if you want to write like Dryden, there's that).

Comment: Thanks. But, if that's the case, I'd rather stomach it looking wrong to me if I can make it flow right to most readers.

Comment: Sounding weird or unnatural is not because of the comma ; the Issue is elsewhere and the original sentence is missing "the" : "He stopped so abruptly that [the] red dust kicked up" : Now , we can take out "that" while leaving out [or leaving in] the comma and it sounds normal or natural.

Comment: It's not missing anything. Commas should be used when they are heard and not elsewhere. A writer has to decided how they want the sentence to _sound_. If you hear a comma intonation, put in a comma. Otherwise, not. In a sentence this short, maybe or maybe not.

Comment: Here, I'd say it's necessary, to preclude the "He stopped, so abruptly red dust kicked up" garden path opportunity. With or without a comma, I'd read it out aloud as the fancy took me (pause? no pause?) ... and perhaps insert 'that' in spite of the author (unless this is direct speech, when I might even attempt the relevant accent).

Comment: Nothing conclusive ; But https://www.google.com/search?q=%22red+dust+kicked+up%22 shows that almost all **sentences** have some article like "**a** haze of red dust" or "**the** red dust", with exceptional cases like Image title or zero article. With the inclusion of "the" in the given example, the sentence looks fine with or without comma.

Comment: You can call it a comma of omission and get away with it. It's not really necessary in your example. But sometimes you must both omit *that* and insert a comma to be clear. Compare: *I was so happy that I wet my pants* and *I was so happy I wet my pants* and *\*I was so happy, that I wet my pants* (incorrect) and *I was so happy, I wet my pants*. If you weren't happy about wetting your pants, use the last one.